# Is there a rails generator for gems that need active-record testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rubygems, generator

I've set up a number of gems manually that require migration generators and testing of the models. Are there any gems to streamline this process?

Answer (score 0):

You can write down all your migration calls and other calls in a custom Rake task.
To get started on how to write your custom rake task, refer here:

- [Railscasts - Custom Rake tasks](http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks)

Comment: I know how to write rake tasks. Was asking a specific question if anybody has packaged up a rails generator ( which has nothing to do with rake ) for this specific problem. If not I might do one myself.